# Does Google App Engine Flexible environment use only one container on one vm instance?

Tags: google-app-engine

When I deploy Google App Engine, i see only the parameters to control the no. of min and max vm instances. When i checked inside vms, it hosts only one container on one vm. If it is doing so, i think its a drawback to go for GAE, rather i would prefer going for a vm instance and then create multiple containers myself.

I've tried searching online, but din't get any specific answer to my question if we can have multiple containers on GAE flexible environment or not. Any answers on this will be highly appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Google App Engine (GAE) Flexible runs only one container per VM and does not support multiple containers at the moment. There was a feature request issued and for now it is not on a roadmap of Google's engineering team. You can track and star this issue [here](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/36113449).

The reason for this is that GAE Flexible is intended to be an automatized environment so that you can focus on actual coding while it takes care of scaling and load-balancing in the background for you. If you want to use more than one container you can deploy it as a separate service in the same app. More advanced control and customization can be done using Kubernetes Engine:

> Kubernetes Engine allows you to deploy multiple containers and groups
>   of containers for each VM instance, which can lead more efficient host
>   VM utilization for microservices with a smaller footprint.

Source: [Google docs](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/containers/deploying-containers)

Comment: Thanks Anna for the reply. much appreciated. For sure without this feature the entire benefit and reasons for containerization fails only for the context of autoscaling.I won't be encouraging any of my clients until this is fixed by google.